# Power from CNO Cycle Fusion

Tags: power, fusion, nuclear-engineering, nucleosynthesis

There are all sorts of projects trying to get power from fusion reactions.

The best known and funded are the Tokamaks, big expensive crush Deuterium and Tritium (He3 sometimes) plasmas and spew neutrons.  Collect the heat and go.

An older fusion generator is the Fusor invented by Farnsworth of TV fame.  Ionized Hydrogen (Deuterium, Tritium, or He3) in a sphere drawn in by an electric potential which then maybe smashes into each other.

The Tokamaks require massive containment, the Fusors have poor reaction rates.

I was wondering if fusing hydrogen into carbon would be a viable option.  A carbon target could be stationary and then hydrogen ions accelerated towards it by a voltage potential.  The idea is to replicate the stellar CNO cycle.  While there is less energy produced here than any of hydrogen-hydrogen fusions, there aren't neutrons flying around and containment seems to be less of an issue since the pressure could be low and all of the action would be linear.